# How do I get rid of the Mindblown and the book recommendations?

Tags: themes, blog

[image: Image of my blog]

I've edited the page, but it does not show the mindblown and Got any book recommendations blocks... I wish to delete these and I think they are artifacts of an old theme.... any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the posts page for the default Twenty-Twenty Three WordPress theme. By default, WordPress displays the posts pages as your home page. It is included as part of the theme files and won't display in the "Pages" tab in your site editor. You'll need to add a new page (or edit the "Sample Page" that is included with the theme), then go to "Settings" > "Reading", then select "A static page" under the "Your homepage displays:" heading, and select your page you edited.

See below:
[image: Settings, reading, your homepage displays settings]

Comment: Thanks, switched the theme (I thought I had done so) and fixed it.